# pyspark: withcolumn Analysis error after column is converted to lowercase

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
+------------+------+
|        food|pounds|
+------------+------+
|       bacon|   4.0|
|STRAWBERRIES|   3.5|
|       Bacon|   7.0|
|STRAWBERRIES|   3.0|
|       BACON|   6.0|
|strawberries|   9.0|
|Strawberries|   1.0|
|      pecans|   3.0|
+------------+------+
```

And the expected output is

```
+------------+------+---------+
|        food|pounds|food_type|
+------------+------+---------+
|       bacon|   4.0|     meat|
|STRAWBERRIES|   3.5|    fruit|
|       Bacon|   7.0|     meat|
|STRAWBERRIES|   3.0|    fruit|
|       BACON|   6.0|     meat|
|strawberries|   9.0|    fruit|
|Strawberries|   1.0|    fruit|
|      pecans|   3.0|    other|
+------------+------+---------+
```

So I essentially defined a new_column based on my logic and applied that on .withcolumn

```
new_column = when((col('food') == 'bacon') | (col('food') == 'BACON') | (col('food') == 'Bacon'), 'meat'
                   ).when((col('food') == 'STRAWBERRIES') | (col('food') == 'strawberries') | (col('food') == 'Strawberries'), 'fruit'
                   ).otherwise('other')
```

And then

```
df.withColumn("food_type", new_column).show()
```

Which works fine. But I wanted to update the `new_column` statement with less code, so rewrite is as below

```
new_column = when(lower(col('food') == 'bacon') , 'meat'
                   ).when(lower(col('food') == 'strawberries'), 'fruit'
                   ).otherwise('other')
```

Now when I do `df.withColumn("food_type", new_column).show()`

I get error

```
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN lower(CAST((`food` = 'bacon') AS STRING)) THEN 'meat' WHEN lower(CAST((`food` = 'strawberries') AS STRING)) THEN 'fruit' ELSE 'other' END' due to data type mismatch: WHEN expressions in CaseWhen should all be boolean type, but the 1th when expression's type is lower(cast((food#165 = bacon) as string));;\n'Project [food#165, pounds#166, CASE WHEN lower(cast((food#165 = bacon) as string)) THEN meat WHEN lower(cast((food#165 = strawberries) as string)) THEN fruit ELSE other END AS food_type#197]\n+- Relation[food#165,pounds#166] csv\n"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parentheses are mismatched.

`new_column = when(lower(col('food')) == 'bacon' , 'meat').when(lower(col('food')) == 'strawberries', 'fruit').otherwise('other')`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share another approach which is more similar to SQL queries and can be more appropriate with more complex and nested conditions as well.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
cond = """case when lower(food) in ('bacon') then 'meat'
            else case when lower(food) in ('strawberries') then 'fruit'
                 else 'other'
                end
            end"""

newdf = df.withColumn("food_type", expr(cond))
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

simplified:

new_column=when(lower(col("food"))=="bacon",'meat').when(lower(col("food"))=='strawberries','fruit').otherwise('other')

df.withColumn("food_type", new_column).show()